# hg equivalant of git revert

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs

I have a commit on a public repository.  I would like this commit to not be there (I've moved that work off to a branch), I obviously don't want to destroy the branch history, basically just do an inverse of that commit.  In git this is just `git revert`, but I'm not using git :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`hg backout`

> hg backout [OPTION]... [-r] REV
>
> reverse effect of earlier changeset
>
> ```
> Commit the backed out changes as a new changeset. The new
> changeset is a child of the backed out changeset.
>
> If you backout a changeset other than the tip, a new head is
> created. This head will be the new tip and you should merge this
> backout changeset with another head.
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with a revision that was created via `hg commit --amend`? I get this error: "abort: cannot backout change that is not an ancestor"